# Cannot update data after reading data from SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, textbox

I'm working on an ASP.NET C# website (I am fairly new to it) and am having trouble with updating a SQL Database with a textbox.

I can update the database with a textbox if it is empty when the page loads, but if i add code to drag SQL data from the database into the text boxes initially, i cannot then change the data on submission.

```
protected void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["overlandconnectionstring2"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string insCmd = "UPDATE Stock SET [make] = @make, [model] = @model where SID ='" + Label1.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand editUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);

            editUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", make.Text);
            editUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model.Text);

            try
            {

                editUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("../stockkey1.aspx");


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Response.Write("<br/>Something really bad happened, Please try again<br/>");
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Is my update code which works fine, but does not work if i add this to the page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {

            Label2.Text = Session["New"].ToString();


            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["overlandconnectionstring2"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Stock where SID='" + Label1.Text + "'", con1);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                make.Text = (myReader["make"].ToString());
                model.Text = (myReader["model"].ToString());
            }
            con1.Close();
```

I have it so that the page requires a log in session which is the session and can be ignored.

with this code it takes the data from the SQL database of the fields i wish to change and inputs it into the textboxes on page load.

if i edit the textboxes after the page load data has been entered and click submit, the  code goes to

```
 try
    {

        editUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("../stockkey1.aspx");


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Write("<br/>Something really bad happened, Please try again<br/>");
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

as exspected but does not fail and display the response but miss out the   editUser.ExecuteNonQuery(); command and redirects straight to the redirection.

my only thought is the .ToString conversion is causing this, but i am unsure.

if you have any ideas I'd love to hear them...

thank you!!

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: There isn't one, it misses out the exception and goes straight to the response.redirect as if it was working fine, just not updating the field.

Comment: Can you run Sql Profiler in Sql Server tools components and check what Sql queries is being fired?

Comment: Don't put data into sql strings like this: `"select * from Stock where SID='" + Label1.Text + "'"` That is evil, wrong, and will result in your app being hacked. You already have examples of using query parameters in your code. Continue doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the page is being posted back in your page load event. Only load the textboxes if isPostback is false. If you dont, then the textboxes get reloaded with each postback, losing your changes before the update

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["New"] != null)
    {

        Label2.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["overlandconnectionstring2"].ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Stock where SID='" + Label1.Text + "'", con1);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            make.Text = (myReader["make"].ToString());
            model.Text = (myReader["model"].ToString());
        }
        con1.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you! i've been going over IsPostBack all day! just needed the correct code in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

did you try 
@model where SID ='" + Label1.Text.Trim() + "'";